# How can I unit test code that sends a SOAP web-service request?

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, axis

I want to write a unit test for some code that generates a SOAP message with an attachment and sends it:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory factory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
conn = factory.createConnection();
conn.call(message, endpoint);
```

where the factory is a `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory`

I don't care about any response coming back but I want to be able to verify the message that gets sent. The code is going to be refactored and I want to make sure it sends that same messages afterwards as before.

Is there a framework i can use to create a mock endpoint that will let me analyse the request in my test? If so, some sample code would be very useful.

Comment: when you say "verify the message that gets sent" are you actually looking to be sure that a request goes out on the wire to some remote service or just that the "conn.call(message, endpoint)" method was called?

Comment: @Angelo I want to analyse the resultant message that the call to conn.call sends. Examine the content of it and make assertions about it in the test. We may be using a different way/library to send in future.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf

Answer (score 4):

There is a java.net project called [WSUnit](https://wsunit.dev.java.net/) that should help. It is basically a listener servlet which listens for messages. You can send messages to it and verify the content of the message using XMLUnit.

Comment: This sounds like what I want, I'll check it out and report back here.

Comment: Thanks, I've added my own answer and explained in it why I went with jetty instead for my particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Use [JMock](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jmock.org%2F&ei=KEeOTP_fL8Ofngfzkf3eCw&usg=AFQjCNGV7mfCWVVXpxCirJScBNvQvBfEUA&sig2=7GXqIA_4dCxYIhYZS3yXow).  JMock allows you to test for behavior rather than state changes.  To do this, you'll need to encapsulate the SOAPCOnnectionFactory.newInstance() method in a diffent object:

```
public class MySOAPConnectionFactory {

    public SOAPConnectionFactory getConnection() {
        return SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
}
```

Use an object of the new class in your code.

```
conn = mySOAPConnectionFactory.getConnection();
conn.call( message, endpoint );
```

Then, in your test, substitute a Mock object for the Factory, which will return a Mock Connection.  Set expectations on the Mock Connection expecting the call you're looking for.

```
final SOAPConnectionFactory mockConnection = mockery.mock(SOAPConnectionFactory.class);
final SOAPConnection mockSoapConnection = mockery.mock(SOAPConnection.class);
foo.setMySOAPConnectionFactory( mockConnectionFactory );
try {
        mockery.checking( new Expectations() {

        {
            atLeast( 1 ).of( mockConnectionFactory ).getConnection();
            will( returnValue( mockSoapConnection ) );
            atLeast( 1 ).of( mockConnection ).call(SOME_MESSAGE, ENDPOINT);
        }
        } );
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to test at a different level to this, I want the actual connection to create whatever HTTP SOAP request it will send, and then I want to verify the contents of that.

Comment: Ah.  Aren't you at that point testing the implemetation of SOAPConnection rather than your code?

Comment: I'm testing what the code actually sends to Web Service. I want to ensure that if the code changes, even the library being used (axis) that the same request is sent. I know ideally each class should be tested at a finer granularity but time won't permit that.

Comment: Sounds like WSUnit is what you want, then.